# Reading an Excel file and writing to text file very slow using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I have the following code in a c# wpf application.  I am reading an Excel file, removing hidden characters and trying to retain the cell formatting, and then writing the data to a pipe delimited text file.  This code looks very straight forward but is very slow.  Any ideas on why and how I can improve the process?

```
    private void ReadWriteExcelData(string strFileName)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Excel.Range range, colrange, rowrange;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
            Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

        Excel.Sheets excelSheets = xlWorkBook.Worksheets;
        if (blnLetExcelDecide)
            {
                range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
            }
            else
            {
                Excel.Range c1 = xlWorkSheet.Cells[lngExcelStartRow, strExcelStartCol];
                Excel.Range c2 = xlWorkSheet.Cells[lngExcelEndRow, strExcelEndCol];
                range = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.get_Range(c1, c2);
            }

            colrange = range.Columns;
            lngNumCols = colrange.Count;
            rowrange = range.Rows;
            lngNumRows = rowrange.Count;

            object[,] values = (object[,])range.Value;
            string[] Fields = new string[lngNumCols];
            int NumRow = 1;

            while (NumRow <= values.GetLength(0))
            {
                strDataRow = "";

                for (lngColCnt = 1; lngColCnt <= lngNumCols; lngColCnt++)
                {
                    strCellData = range[NumRow, lngColCnt].Text;
                    strCellData = strCellData.TrimStart(' ');


                    if (strCellData == null)
                    {
                        strCellData = string.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strCellData = strCellData.Replace("\r\n", " ").Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " ");
                    }

                    if (lngColCnt == lngNumCols)
                    {
                        strDataRow += strCellData;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strDataRow += strCellData + "|";
                    }
                }

                WriteDataRow(strDataRow, strFullOutputFileName);

                if (NumRow % intModNumber == 0)
                {
                    dblProgressPct = ((double)NumRow / (double)lngNumRows);
                    dblProgress = Math.Round((dblProgressPct * 100), 0);
                    prgIndicator.Width = dblProgress * 4;
                    lblPrctPrgrs.Content = dblProgress + "%";

                    grdProgressIndicator.InvalidateVisual();
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                }

                NumRow++;
            }
       }
```

Here is the WriteDataRow routine:

```
    public void WriteDataRow(string strDataRow, string strFullFileName)
    {
        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@strFullFileName, true, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
        {
            file.WriteLine(strDataRow);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How much data ? How slow ?  If you comment out the "write" is it still slow?

Comment: You'e pulling the range contents into `values`, but looping over the range to get the cell contents - why not use `values` for this ?  EDIT: never mind  -you want Text not Value...   Any trip between your C# and Excel requires a call to be marshalled across the boundary between two processes: there's a lot of overhead in this.

Comment: Sorry didn't think to give the file size.  The Excel file I am working with is 68 columns by 3652 rows.  It takes about 5 1/2 minutes to execute.

Comment: And you surely can use some [StringBuilders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) in there, replacing the strCellData and strDataRow concatenation

Comment: Just as a test - if you use the `values` array in place of the individual Text values, what is the performance like?

Comment: If I use values the performance is way better, like 15 seconds.  With that said is there a way to use values but maintain the cell formatting?  I tried checking the cell to see if it was numeric and then doing the following:

    strNumberFormat = range[NumRow,lngColCnt].NumberFormat.ToString(); 
    double dblCellValue = double.Parse(strCellData);
     strCellData = dblCellValue.ToString(strNumberFormat);

But this didn't hande number formats like [#,##0] or cuastom formats like 00000-0000

Comment: There's no way to get the Text values from a range in one shot.  As a workaround you could try creating a VBA function which returns an array of the cell Text values given a range object: that should be much faster since it would run entirely within the Excel process, but I'm not that familiar with passing arrays back to C# from VBA...

Comment: Get a profiler and tell us what's actually slow rather than letting us speculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a check for a format type of "#,##0.00_)Red.  Only if this cell had this format then I did Convert.ToString(range[NumRow, lngColCnt].Value2).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach involving using some VBA to read all of the cells' Text values.

First, create an xlsm file containing this function in a regular module:

```
Public Function GetText(strWB As String, strSheet As String, _
                        strAddress As String) As Variant()
    Dim rng As Range, arr() As Variant, r As Long, c As Long
    Set rng = Workbooks(strWB).Worksheets(strSheet).Range(strAddress)
    rng.Columns.AutoFit 'avoid getting "######" !
    ReDim arr(0 To rng.Rows.Count - 1, 0 To rng.Columns.Count - 1)
    For r = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        arr(r - 1, c - 1) = rng.Cells(r, c).Text
    Next c
    Next r
    GetText = arr
End Function
```

After opening your data file, open the file with the macro:

```
Excel.Workbook xlCodeWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Folder\Stuff\TheMacro.xlsm");
```

Then call the macro:

```
object[,] values = xlApp.Run("'" + xlCodeWb.Name + "'!GetText", 
                   xlWorkBook.Name, xlWorkSheet.Name, range.Address);
```

`values` is now a 2D array of all of the Text values from the sheet, without the overhead of having to pick out each one in a separate call across the process boundaries.  You can iterate over the array and write the "cleaned-up" values to your file.

BTW you should probably consider opening and writing to the output file in your main method: open it *once* and then write the lines, closing it only when you're done.  No need to re-open it for every line.

Comment: This Excel macro sounds good but how do I distribute this application and macro together?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with distributing C# desktop apps but could you add it as a resource in your forms app?  You can then extract it to a temporary location at runtime.

Comment: I think I have found a work around.  The reason I was doing this

strCellData = range[NumRow, lngColCnt].Text;

Was because when a field has a fromat type of "#,##0.00_)[Red](#,##0.00) the result in strCellData contained #,##0.00_)[Red](#,##0.00).  What I did was:

if (strNumberFormat.IndexOf("[Red]") > 0 )
                                                {
                                                    strCellData = Convert.ToString(range[NumRow, lngColCnt].Value2); 
                                                }